# ROS Melodic OpenCV xfeatures2d

Tags: ros, opencv, ros-melodic, opencv3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On ROS Melodic ros-melodic-opencv3 doesn't exist anymore as e.g. on ROS Kinetic. Instead it is recommended to install libopencv-dev http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Migration#opencv , however, this package does not contain xfeatures2d, neither does libopencv-contrib-dev.

How am I supposed do install xfeatures2d (SURF, SIFT, etc.)? Do I have to build OpenCV 3 now from source?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312669/ros-melodic-opencv-xfeatures2d/) by [sam_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/22467/sam_123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2019-01-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since xfeatured2d module is not part of OpenCV anymore, but now included in `opencv_contrib` (https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/xfeatures2d) you need to build and install from source and add those modules to the build configuration.

Summarizing what you can find in the following link (https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-18-04/).

1. Install the necessary packages
2. Clone the OpenCV source code and mostly important for you, clone the `opencv_contrib` repository
3. Set up the OpenCV build with CMake. Since xfeatured2d is a nonfree module, you will need to set `OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON`. The whole command would look something like this:

> ```
> cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \  
>         -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \  
>         -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \  
>         -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \  
>         -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_build/opencv_contrib/modules \  
>         -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON .. \  
>         -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON ..
> ```

4. Compile OpenCV
5. Install OpenCV

---

Originally posted by [sapient84](https://answers.ros.org/users/25429/sapient84/) with karma: 51 on 2019-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/22467/sam_123/) on 2019-02-07**:
Yeah, I build now our own OpenCV Contrib debian packages. No idea why they didn't include all the contrib features into the "official" debian packages.

**Comment by [Elektron97](https://answers.ros.org/users/72984/elektron97/) on 2021-07-13**:
How I can add this module in build configuration?